# Functions returning an object with the same attributes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

So my problem is the following:
I have the two functions
getDatesAndStringOfTimespan(timeSpan, goBack) returns {from, to}
limitFromAndTo(from, to, fromLimit, toLimit) returns {from, to}

I now want to do the following:
`let { from, to } = getDatesAndStringOfTimespan(timeSpan, goBack)`
`{ from, to } = limitFromAndTo(from, to, fromLimit, toLimit)`

But it says 'Declaration or statement expected.' I know I could do
`let { from, to } = getDatesAndStringOfTimespan(timeSpan, goBack)`
`let object = limitFromAndTo(from, to, fromLimit, toLimit)`
`from = object.from`
`to = object.to`

It just seems like there is a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this would be the right way:  

`let { from, to } = getDatesAndStringOfTimespan(timeSpan, goBack);
    [ from, to ] = limitFromAndTo(from, to, fromLimit, toLimit)`
But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two other ways of doing this.

1. Wrap the second assignment in parentheses to help the js compiler to understand what's happening (I'm not recommending this, just making your implementation possible in practice)

```
let { from, to } = getDatesAndStringOfTimespan(timeSpan, goBack);
({ from, to } = limitFromAndTo(from, to, fromLimit, toLimit))
```

2. Only destructure the second values

```
const dates = getDatesAndStringOfTimespan(timeSpan, goBack)
const { from, to } = limitFromAndTo(dates.from, dates.to, fromLimit, toLimit)
```

I would prefer #2 in a code review, as it's clearer to see what's going on - no magic brackets, and more readable

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
In this case I will go for the second option, but this comes up in my code every now and then and sometimes I may consider the first one.
Never really learned Javascript, just plain Java :/